# Fading top and bottom edges of a semi transparent and scrollable div with a background video

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a div that contains a fixed height and inside it there is another one with `overflow: auto` that lets the div be scrollable. The parent div is semi-transparent and in the background of everything there is a video being played.

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">

  <div class="fade-top"/>

  <div class="fade-bottom"/>

  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus, ipsam, sit! 
    Adipisci, aspernatur minima nobis at distinctio eveniet sunt aliquid, iure 
    laboriosam. Possimus dolore earum delectus ipsa, sequi blanditiis veritatis!Lorem 
    ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus, ipsam, sit! Adipisci, 
    aspernatur minima nobis at distinctio eveniet sunt aliquid, iure laboriosam.
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent{
  height: 2rem;
  position: relative
  background: hsla(180, 2%, 8%, 0.76);
}

.fade-top {
  poistion: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, hsla(180, 2%, 8%, 0.76) 20%, transparent 100%);
  height: 50px;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.fade-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, $content-bg-elementum 20%, transparent 100%);
  height: 50px;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.text {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Question:

How do I make the top and bottom divs fade gradually to mix with the parent semi-transparent color?

Current state, the red board has to be mixed with the parent background and not cut by the height of the parent:

[image: current]

Answer (score 1):

You can use After and before for fade top and bottom instead of using extra divs.
The code will be like.

HTML

```
 <div class="parent">
 <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus, ipsam, sit! 
    Adipisci, aspernatur minima nobis at distinctio eveniet sunt aliquid, iure 
    laboriosam. Possimus dolore earum delectus ipsa, sequi blanditiis veritatis!Lorem 
    ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus, ipsam, sit! Adipisci, 
    aspernatur minima nobis at distinctio eveniet sunt aliquid, iure laboriosam.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus, ipsam, sit! 
    Adipisci, aspernatur minima nobis at distinctio eveniet sunt aliquid, iure 
    laboriosam. Possimus dolore earum delectus ipsa, sequi blanditiis veritatis!Lorem 
    ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus, ipsam, sit! Adipisci, 
    aspernatur minima nobis at distinctio eveniet sunt aliquid, iure laboriosam.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus, ipsam, sit! 
    Adipisci, aspernatur minima nobis at distinctio eveniet sunt aliquid, iure 
    laboriosam. Possimus dolore earum delectus ipsa, sequi blanditiis veritatis!Lorem 
    ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus, ipsam, sit! Adipisci, 
    aspernatur minima nobis at distinctio eveniet sunt aliquid, iure laboriosam.
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent{

 position: relative;
width: 600px;
  background: hsla(180, 2%, 8%, 0.76);
  color: white;
}
.parent:before{
content: "";
  width:100%;
  height:40px;
  background: linear-gradient(black, transparent);
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.parent::after{
content: "";
  width:100%;
  height:40px;
  background: linear-gradient(transparent, black);
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
.text {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 200px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/suffiyan1/pen/vYeyjZo

Comment: This is not what I am looking for, the parent div is inside another div which has this `hsla` background, and as there is a video on the background, the color of the background changes a lot. I am updating the image so you have a better idea.

Comment: As you can see now, the fade has to match the parent `.parent` background

Comment: Can you share any references?
So I can understand your use of text with video.
Is it something like this? https://tkxel.com/

Comment: In the Image, I see there is a video with controls, while you are saying it is a background video and then you want text on top of the video with a fade to make difference between text and video?

Comment: Just edited the image again so you can have a better context, the fade is being cut by the height of the parent element, and this is exactly what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: means you don't want prominent fade edges? and all of the thing you are looking for has been achieved?

Comment: Exactly, I am looking for prominent fading edges. This is the only thing I am looking for.

Comment: Check the Codepen link I have updated the CSS Background color values hope it will help. If you want more fade then you can change RGBA values.
I have used 3 value linear gradient which you can use and edit accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally found a way around this using the CSS property `mask`. Like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="parent fade-top-bottom">

  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus, ipsam, sit! 
    Adipisci, aspernatur minima nobis at distinctio eveniet sunt aliquid, iure 
    laboriosam. Possimus dolore earum delectus ipsa, sequi blanditiis veritatis!Lorem 
    ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus, ipsam, sit! Adipisci, 
    aspernatur minima nobis at distinctio eveniet sunt aliquid, iure laboriosam.
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent{
  height: 2rem;
  position: relative
  background: hsla(180, 2%, 8%, 0.76);
}

.fade-top-bottom {
    mask:
    linear-gradient(to top,  transparent 10%, black 80%, transparent 100%),
    linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 10%, black 80%, transparent 100%);
  }

.text {
  overflow: auto;
}
```